# Python MySQL Insert new row to existing table based on its' primary key order

Tags: python, mysql, insert, sql-order-by

I'm struggling to come up with a logic how to insert a new row to an existing mysql table at the right place based on the timestamp. My primary key in the table is the date in format "2020-10-01 12:00:00". PS: I am checking for duplicates in advance, so new row will indeed be "new" to the table.

Basically, I have a table with data sorted by timestamps and I am trying to fill the gaps in my records. Some gaps might be older than all existing timestamps, some inbetween the existing ones and some might be after the existing ones. I am trying to figure out how to insert a new row at the right place thus keeping the order correct.

So far I was trying with something like:

```
add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(first_name, last_name, hire_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" ORDER by hire_date)

data_employee = ('ABC', 'XYZ', 'Date')

cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I believe the 'order' of a MySQL table is an abstraction. You can only insert things in the order they are inserted. The 'ORDER BY' clause can be used when you retrieve the data with a select statement, so that the rows are sorted the way they need to be. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks a lot for your reply!